# R XML Enforce DDT File

Tags: r, xml

Using the `XML` package for R, how can I enforce the use of a DTD file? The following is reported to parse ok, although the second child (description) is not defined as an acceptable child by the DTD file, I would expect an error to be thrown of some kind.

**test.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE model SYSTEM "test.dtd">
<model>
  <name>Test</name>
  <description>Some Description</description>
</model>
```

**test.dtd**

```
<!--  __ MAIN ELEMENT __ -->
<!ELEMENT model(name) >
<!ELEMENT name (#PCDATA) >
```

**script.R**

```
library(XML)
doc = xmlParse("test.xml")
xmlToList(doc)
```

**Output**

```
doc = xmlParse("test.xml")
xmlToList(doc)

$name
[1] "Test"
$description
[1] "Some Description"
```

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: No, and I am still looking.